# Get return values of code with tokenizer

Tags: php, token, tokenize

I'm trying to parse PHP source code with the `token_get_all()`. So far everything worked out with that function, but now i need a way to get the return values of methods.

Identifying where a `return` is done isn't the problem. I just see no way of getting the piece of code that comes after the `return` value.

For example for this piece of code:

```
<?php
    class Bla {
        public function Test1()
        {
            $t = true;

            if($t) {
                return 1;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        public function Test2()
        {
            echo "bbb";
            return; // nothing is returned
        }

        public function Test3()
        {
            echo "ccc";
            $someval1 = 1;
            $someval2 = 2;

            return ($someval + $otherval)*2;
        }
    }
?>
```

I'm using `get_token_all()` to identify where a `return` is done:

```
$newStr  = '';
$returnToken = T_RETURN;
$tokens = token_get_all($source);
foreach ($tokens as $key => $token)
{    
    if (is_array($token))
    {
        if (($token[0] == $returnToken))
        {
            // found return, now get what is returned?
        }
        else
        {
            $token = $token[1];
        }
    }

    $newStr .= $token;
}
```

I have no clue how to get the piece of code that is actually returned. That is what i want to get.

Anyone any idea how i could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this might help. Though I curious to know what you are ultimately trying to do.

```
$tokens = token_get_all($str);
$returnCode = '';
$returnCodes = array();
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    // If return statement start collecting code.
    if (is_array($tokens) && $token['0'] == T_RETURN) {
        $returnCode .= $token[1];
        continue;
    }

    // if we started collecting code keep collecting.
    if (!empty($returnCode)) {
        // if we get to a semi-colon stop collecting code
        if ($token === ';') {
            $returnCodes[] = substr($returnCode, 6);
            $returnCode = '';
        } else {            
            $returnCode .= isset($token[1]) ? $token[1] : $token;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking about the same idea. I guess this is the  best way to do it. Atleast it works out great for my purposes.